# Android, Retrofit catch specific response code for all requests

Tags: android, http, retrofit, okhttp

I have Retrofit Rest client interface with more than 40 http calls. I initialize my RestClient like this:

```
public class RestClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://example.com/";

    private static final int TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 30;

    private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(getInterceptor())
        .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();


    private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();

    private RestClient() {

    }

    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor getInterceptor() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
        return interceptor;
    }

    public static MyService request() {
        return retrofit.create(MyService.class);
    }

}
```

All requests, except authorization, requires special token. When this token expires REST API responds with `403` code error.

I can't add checking for this code response from each of my API call, because there are more than 100 api calls in my application.

Is it possible to somehow catch `403 response code` in the level of my `RestClient` class so I could open Authorization Activity again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think `403` is wrong, `401` may be right. If you are sure When this token expires REST API responds with `403` code error. You can't use `Authenticator` which will be used when 401 happens. So, you need use `Interceptor`. you can create `TokenInterceptor` implements `Interceptor`

```
public class TokenInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        if (response.code() == 403) {
            doSomething();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

okHttpClient add this TokenInterceptor.